# How to create multiple collections in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I currently have a users collection. I want to create a logs collection and join them together. Right now I can create the users collection through .createCollection. But is it possible to create multiple collections in one go? Or do I have to do it through two separate .createCollection operations?

Comment: You can create a JavaScript file, place all the commands in it - create collection, its indexes, add documents, etc. Then run the 
JavaScript file from _mongo shell_ or from OS prompt. See [execute JS files with mongo commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/index.html#execute-a-javascript-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list of collection names and then loop through it and call `db.createCollection` operations on mongo shell easily:

e.g:

```
> var collectionList = ["A", "B"];
> collectionList.forEach(function(collectionName) {db.createCollection(collectionName)})
```

After completion of the above command, just check the list of all collections:

```
> show collections
A
B
```

For details about the create collection visit the official documentation [createCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db-createcollection)

And for reference to other collections, please check the documentation of [DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs)

Answer (score 0):

To create a collection https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_collection.htm

To do a join https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/